# Fedex providing API to create users?

Tags: php, api, fedex

I have to create users in fedex using API? Is there any API available in fedex to create users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fedex does have a PHP SDK which works well and it looks like [JeremyDunn](https://github.com/JeremyDunn/php-fedex-api-wrapper/tree/master/examples) has put together a Symfony focused Fedex project.